# Run independent, Parallel or Multithread to increase speed

Tags: python, mongodb, parallel-processing, bigdata, pymongo

I have `2 separate collections`. Each has information of hotels in the world , each provided by different companies, but both contain `same information`,
each collection have information like gps, name , country, city , email , fax and tel
the problem is name(gps , info and ...) are **`changed`**, I wrote a similarity algorithm to find match of a record in collection A with collection B, 
I have no problem with algorithm, **my problem is about run-time!**

**my solution :**

compare a record from A with all records in collection B and find best match (this part use similiarity algorith and not my question),

**problem  :**

I write this with `pymongo` and raw `python` code, is there any module to increase speed? (even parallel is good)

each collection  has 160k record

Comment: how does your current queries look like? Are they running slow and adding slowness to your code?

Comment: i handle algorith with python not by queries in pymongo ,just check city and country in mongo, because algorith it self is coplex , as i say i have 2 for (not parallel not multitread).